# I could be hit by lightning

Tags: modal-verbs

1. I **could** be run over by a bus tomorrow.
2. I **could** be hit by lightning.
3. I **could** die tomorrow.

Can I replace the "could"s with "might"s in the examples above with no change in meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you could, though I feel it does change the “flavour” of the expression somewhat, particularly in the case of the lightning example, and makes it sound as if you are more seriously suggesting this might happen to you.

So you could, but I’d stick with “could”. With “could”, you’re purely stating that there is **technically** a possibility, but with “might”/“may” you’re suggesting more of a real possibility or belief (these comments are often made as an exaggeration to highlight that something less sinister may happen, but there’s generally no real belief that the thing you’re saying could happen might happen).

Comment: Thank you. One more question: *One doesn't know what **could/might** happen tomorrow.*---Which one of "could" and "might" would you prefer?

Comment: I would prefer “might” in that context. “Could” seems to suggest, “One isn’t aware of all of the possibilities of what might happen tomorrow.”

Comment: I'm a little confused. Just one more question: *He was jailed five years ago and **could/might** be released next year.*---Which one of "could" and "might" would you prefer?

Comment: It is confusing. I suppose “could” implies technical possibility, and “might” implies a degree of probability/likelihood. With the jail example you could use either. In such a context, I feel that possibility implies some probability. It’s different to saying one might be struck by lightning. If he could be released, then that’s because there’s some reason that this may/might be so, otherwise we wouldn’t say it. It is a confusing thing, and I wouldn’t worry too much about getting it wrong, as you wouldn’t be terribly misunderstood - let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: You say: *I suppose “could” implies technical possibility, and “might” implies a degree of probability/likelihood.*---Consider this "suggestion", please: *We **might/could** meet again after New Year, if you're agreeable.*--I think neither indicates **probability** here, but only possibility. Am I right?

Comment: I would say the same rule still applies. “Could” implies “it’s an option for us to meet, if we so choose”, whereas “might” would actually not be idiomatic in this case, and would actually sound more like “we might see each other” (as opposed to “meet up”), for example, if we were both going to be at the same event, or something like that; either that, or it would mean the same as “could”, but would sound quite posh/upper class, and maybe a little archaic.

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between: *He was jailed five years ago and **might** be released next year.* and *One **might** be hit by lightning* or *One **might** die tomorrow*? Are we **predicting** something in all of these examples? In the latter example, does the speaker know who that "one" is, but just don't want to mention his name?

Comment: I doubt anyone would ever say “one” in such a context unless they were mimicking “posh”. As for the difference between the two contexts, with the jail example, you really believe there is a chance he will be released, whereas, with the lightning example, it’s usually a “beyond belief” exaggeration used to communicate the idea that while you’ve said someone can depend on you, you cannot absolutely guarantee that you will be around at that time. E.g.: Person A: Will you definitely call me tomorrow? Person B: Well, I could get struck by lightning, but yes, I’ll call you.

Comment: Last question: When suggesting a sentence, for example: XYZ, to someone, we use "You/I/one **would** say: XYZ" or "You/I/one **could** say: XYZ" or "You/I/one **might** say: XYZ". What is the difference between "could" and "might" here? Does "might" indicate probability and "could" possibility or both indicate only possibility?

Comment: I’d say the possibility/probability rule still applies technically, however, in that context, they’d both be taken to mean the same thing. “Might”, as the “probability” option, probably sounds a little more presumptive, perhaps almost as if you were putting words in someone’s mouth, however, it would usually be said very politely, in a tone that lets the person know it’s merely a suggestion - it’s also quite an upper class/elegant way of speaking, and perhaps almost a little authoritarian, e.g., something a professor might say to a student; it perhaps has more of an “advice giving” tone to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Since you used "might" in the sentence: "*something a professor **might** say to a student*" in your last comment, I've got another question for you: we sometimes use "might" to give examples (as you did above) or to describe a series of events/ a narrative (we normally use simple present tense in narratives, but sometimes we use "might", for example: "You say...then he says...then I might say...then he might say...". Is that "might" replaceable by "could"? Does it indicate probability too?

Comment: With the professor example, if we were to say "could", we could argue that anyone could technically say it, so the example would be redundant - so by using might I'm hinting at probability. With your further example, you could say "could", but again, it's a probability case, where we're making guesses at what someone might say, and not just describing what they could say, which could be anything. It would be understood, but I would reserve "could" for situations where we're emphasising the possibility that someone could say something - let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks. Last sentence: *If the astronaut momentarily lost radio contact with earth, the whole mission **could/might** be ruined.*---Are "might" and "could" both possible in this sentence? Do they indicate possibility or probability?

Comment: For me, this would be a “possibility” scenario. Usually, when we’re talking about extreme/dire consequences, we’re emphasising the possibility, which is itself enough to cause alarm. Although, I would agree that both would be acceptable in that scenario, but “might” feels like it has a much weaker effect, almost as though it were inconsequential.

Comment: Is "ruined" in the sentence *"If the astronaut momentarily lost radio contact with earth, the whole mission could/might be **ruined**"* an adjective or a verb?

Comment: This kind of theory isn’t my strong point, but in this case it would be a verb. We are saying that the loss of contact might ruin the mission, as opposed to describing the mission as potentially reaching a state of ruin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, effort, and patience. I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem at all; I’m sorry I couldn’t be clearer in parts, but you will get this with practice/reading/listening. :)